# Searching book for abelian variety

Tags: abelian-varieties

Do you have interesting books presenting abelian variety (over an arbitrary field k) using the scheme point of view? Most of the lectures I know use the point of view presented in the first chapter of Hartshorne (so without scheme).

I'm looking for something which presents the modern aspects/questions of those objects.

Comment: See Milne, *Abelian varieties*. There will probably be some new materials in a few months, after the Arizona Winter School. See also a book (project?) by Edixhoven, van der Geer and Moonen eg here: http://van-der-geer.nl/~gerard/AV.pdf .

Comment: Wow : the book of van der Geer and Moonen is great. That's what I was looking for!!!

Comment: To add to Aphelli's answer, there is also Mumford's Abelian Varieties (middle of the book on onwards), and Polishchuk's Abelian Varieties, Theta Functions and the Fourier Transform.

Comment: Hello, many thanks to you!